# How is rationalism still used today?

Tags: empiricism, rationality

This was a test question in my class I thought I had the right answer to, but apparently got wrong. How would you answer this?

If experimental sciences demonstrate that empiricism has "won the day", what role has rationalism to play, now?

Comment: Empiricism is neither the only alternative to rationalism, various forms of anti-intellectualism and spiritualism are as well, nor has it "won the day". Traditional forms of rationalism, with platonic forms or innate ideas, are indeed scarce, but the same is true of traditional empiricism, and much of current analytic philosophy fuses the spirit of both, see [rationalism](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Rationalism) and [contemporary rationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalism#Contemporary_rationalism).

Comment: An odd question. What has changed that leads you to ask 'What role has rationality to play now?'.Is it not the same as ever? In what sense has empiricism 'won the day'?.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the user!

Answer (score 2):

## Rationalism

The (contemporary) philosophical linguistics of Noam Chomsky is widely regarded as containing distinct and ineliminable elements of rationalism:

> Noam Chomsky's rationalist account of the human mind has won many
> adherents and attracted many critics. What has been little noticed on
> either side of the debate is that Chomsky's rationalism is best viewed as a
> pair of quite distinct doctrines about the mental mechanisms responsible
> for language acquisition. One of these doctrines, the one I will call rigid
> rationalism, entails the other, which I call anti-empiricism, but the entailment is not mutual. Rigid rationalism is much the stronger of the two.
> What is more, the argument Chomsky offers for rigid rationalism is quite
> distinct from the argument for anti-empiricism. (Stephen P. Stich, 'Between Chomskian Rationalism and Popperian Empiricism', The British Journal for the Philosophy of Science, Vol. 30, No. 4 (Dec., 1979), pp.
> 329-347: 329.)

I settle for this brief extract as evidence that it is not plausible to say unqualifiedly that 'empiricism has won the day'.

## Empiricism

If we reject Chomsky's rationalist account of the mind, we cannot safely infer that 'empiricism has won the day', because empiricism is beset with difficulties regardless of the fate and prospects of rationalism, Chomskian or other.

> Classical empiricism points to a
> unique putative source to ground and test all judgment: 'experience is
> our sole source of information'. A naive appeal to experience assumes
> that there is never any question about what the deliverances of experience actually are, nor about their meaning or significance. It assumes
> furthermore that the implications-namely, which theories are in ac-
> cord with experience and which in conflict-is evident and unequivocal.
> But these assumptions are not tenable. (Bas C. van Fraassen, Sola Experientia?--Feyerabend's Refutation of Classical Empiricism', Philosophy of Science, Vol. 64, Supplement. Proceedings of the 1996 Biennial
> Meetings of the Philosophy of Science Association. Part II: Symposia Papers (Dec., 1997),
> pp. S385-S395: S388.)

Much more could be said and probably will be said in other answers about present-day rationalism and empiricism. Even my minimal evidence makes clear, however, that the claim that 'empiricism has won the day' and that rationalism goes begging does not sustain scrutiny.

I anticipate the objection that the terms 'rationalism' and 'empiricism' stand in need of conceptual clarification. I couldn't agree more, but then the greater the need for clarification the less the fruitfulness of the question in its current formulation.

Answer (score 1):

To give the most direct response, much of European-derived philosophy — including social theory and critical theory — is rationalist. The more we deal with complex cognitive constructs, the more subjective the subject of our analysis becomes, and the less we can rely on the tools of empiricism. For a clear example, if we want to look at systemic racial biases, empirical analysis is not sufficient. Empirical analysis will tell us that there is a disparity in the treatment of different racial groups, but it will not explain that disparity. To make the case that the disparity is due to systematic racial bias, we need to examine the cognitive constructs that *cause* the behavior, and that can only be done through rational introspection.

Empiricism is geared towards the analysis of objects that do not introspect: i.e., the bulk of the material world. But once we start looking at dasein (in Heidegger's sense) we are forced into rationalism.

Speaking more generally, the dispute between rationalism and empiricism has always been artificial: more of a turf-war than a real philosophical dispute. I'd even suggest that the distinction is rapidly disappearing. Modern rationalism usually bases itself in empirical research of one sort or other (beginning, I suppose, with Durkheim's argument for *social facts*). Likewise, empiricism has increasingly stumbled over the fact that its core principle — empirical observation — is bounded by poorly understood and highly subjective cognitive states. In fact, the historical point of contention between empiricism and rationalism was religion, with Anglophone university systems pushing back against any incursion of theology into what they saw as 'scientific' philosophy. But aside from fundamentalist holdouts, that dispute is largely defunct. Religious doctrine no longer presents a serious hazard to scientific investigation in the academic world, so empiricist philosophers are increasingly comfortable using rationalist techniques.

Comment: this was helpful you guys. You have many different opinions from what I have heard previously. Im taking note!